# How to make action on scrolling accordion div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an accordion menu. And I want to make action on scrolling to the end of accordion item content.
Im trying to do

```
$("#Akordeon1Content").scroll(function() {        
    if($("#Akordeon1Content").scrollTop() === $("#AkordeonContainer").height() - $("#Akordeon1Content").height()) {
        alert("dsadas");
    }
}
```

but it doesn't working. Someone have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: which function do you use to open the accordion?

Comment: I wrote a function below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a new paramter:

```
animate(lastTick, timeLeft, closingId, openingId, callback)
```

add this function when you clear the timeout in your animation:

```
callback();
```

do not forget to pass your function into the animate function:

```
animate(new Date().getTime(),TimeToSlide,Akordeon_otw,nID, function( ){[...]});
```

and dont forget to pass your callback into the next animation:

```
setTimeout("animate(" + curTick + "," + timeLeft + ",'" + closingId + "','" + openingId + "', " + callback + ")", 33);}
```

Comment: Hmm ye but that will do automaticly action when the acordeon open to full. And i want to do action when i reach the bottom of this akordeon content. Beacouse i want to do somthing like loading more data on scrolling bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
function otworz(index)
{
var nID = "Akordeon" + index + "Content";
var nazwa = nID;
if(Akordeon_otw  === nID)
    nID = ''; 
animate(new Date().getTime(),TimeToSlide,Akordeon_otw,nID);
Akordeon_otw  = nID;
}

function animate(lastTick, timeLeft, closingId, openingId)
{  
var curTick = new Date().getTime();
var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

var opening = (openingId === '') ? null : document.getElementById(openingId);
var closing = (closingId === '') ? null : document.getElementById(closingId);

if(timeLeft <= elapsedTicks)
{
if(opening !== null)
  opening.style.height = ContentHeight + 'px';

if(closing !== null)
{
  closing.style.display = 'none';
  closing.style.height = '0px';
}
return;
}

timeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
var newClosedHeight = Math.round((timeLeft/TimeToSlide) * ContentHeight);

if(opening !== null)
{
if(opening.style.display !== 'block')
  opening.style.display = 'block';
opening.style.height = (ContentHeight - newClosedHeight) + 'px';
} 

if(closing !== null)
closing.style.height = newClosedHeight + 'px';

setTimeout("animate(" + curTick + "," + timeLeft + ",'"
  + closingId + "','" + openingId + "')", 33);
 }
```